# Jquery to Download Result File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I need to create a button that on click says 'loading' and then spits out a spreadsheet with the results from a table that was created by the user. I have the code working as a link, but not as a button. How can I solve this?

This is the script to create the table and spits the result in a spreadsheet from the link specified:

```
makeTable = function(query) {
    var q = encodeURIComponent(query);
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Filter results:"},
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy":true,
        "sAjaxSource": $.sprintf('http://...?q=%s',q),
        "aoColumns":[
            {"mData":"id", "sWidth": "20px", "sTitle":"ID"},
            {"mData":"chamber", "sWidth": "10px", "sTitle":"Chamber"},
            {"mData":"date", "sWidth": "85px", "sTitle":"Date"},
            {"mData":"yea","sTitle":"Vote","sWidth":"80px"},
            {"mData":"descriptionShort", "sWidth": "200px","sTitle":"Description"}
        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html($.sprintf('<a onclick="setviz(\'%s\');setview(\'visualize\')">%s</a>',aData['id'],aData['id'])).attr("title", "Click to explore this vote");
            $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html($.sprintf('%s-%s', aData['yea'], aData['no']));
            $('td:eq(4)', nRow).attr("title",aData['description']);
            resultids.push(aData['id']); // build vector vote ids (nothing to do with the table)
            return nRow;
        },  
        "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
            $('#downloadExcel').attr('href','http://...?ids=' + resultids.join()); // Make download link
        }
    });                
}
```

In the body of the HTML I have the following code:

```
<div id='results'>
  <div class="jumbotron">   
    <div class="container special">
      <div class="table">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped"></table><br/>

        <a id="downloadExcel" href="">Download</a><br></br>

        <a onclick="oper_executar('downloadExcel')" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button">Download</a><br></br>

        </div><!-- table -->
      </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- jumbotron -->    
  </div><!-- results -->
```

The link does exactly what I expected, but the button does not!

Help?

Comment: <a href="javascript:oper_executar('downloadExcel')" maybe ?

Comment: why dont you use:
<input type="button" value="displayedText" onclick="yourcode()"></input> ? 
havent seen your a-> role="button" construct before =)

Comment: role="button" is further information for screenreaders and describes elements which cause a response/action, as buttons usually do; [using the button-role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role). I believe the provided HTML-code is the working code using a link. Please verify/falsify this and/or provide the code that does not work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<button id="downloadExcel">Download</button>
```

Change your link to button.

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
            $('#downloadExcel').click(function(){
                  window.location = 'http://...?ids=' + resultids.join();
            })      
}
```

Setting the url to the `window.location` will trigger the download of the file. you can also try `window.location.href`